# how to check to modify the definition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel
(roomNum INTEGER NOT NULL,
arrD DATE NOT NULL,
depD DATE NOT NULL,
guestName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (roomNum, arrDate));
```

how can I modify the definition to keep a check so that no room is booked before the departure date of previous allocation.

Comment: Since mysql does not support the check constraint, you cannot achieve the expected behaviour by changing the table definition. You may use a trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `INSERT` with a `NOT EXISTS` clause to check the validity of the date:

```
INSERT INTO Hotel (roomNum, arrD, depD, guestName)
SELECT 1, '2017-02-08', '2017-02-11', 'Tim Biegeleisen'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Hotel WHERE roomNum = 1 AND depD > '2017-02-08')
```

I don't think that modifying the table definition will make it possible to enforce your logic.

Comment: Can we redesign or add some fields in the table for that check??

Comment: Check the comment by @shadow ... MySQL does not support such a constraint.  The answer I gave would result in no insert happening if the arrival date were before any departure date.